# Next js dynamic image in og-image tag in head

Tags: reactjs, facebook, next.js

I have a nextjs application. I used head of next js to generate head of each page dynamically.
the problem is og-image or og-description are not rendered when I use facebook open graph share link. and the image of shared URL is a blank image. here is a example of my code:

```
<Head>
   <meta
      name="og:title"
      content={
        product ? 'product['name'] : 'Product'
      }
      />
        
      <meta name="og:type" content="Product" />
        
      <meta
          name="og:image"
          content={product ? product.galleries[0].gallery.media[0].file : ''}
        />
</Head>
```

Do you have any solutions for this problem ? same thing happens when I use twitter open graph link.

example of facebook share function:

```
  const facebookShareLink =
    'https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=' +
    shareUrl +
    stripQueryStringAndHashFromPath(route)
```

`shareUrl` is a variable from my config that is my main URL and it concats with current product url

Comment: Facebook does a HTTP request to your server. The meta tags in the HTML you return needs to contain the data you want them to contain. So you have to render it on the server.